# C# Zedgraph Exception Help..me

Tags: zedgraph

I am using ZedGraph.

I am drawing a chart by receiving the values in real time.

---

zedGraphControl1?.AxisChange();

---

object reference not set to an instance of an object.
A message appears saying...

I don't know the cause.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the Zedgraph. It means you must allocate memory for its properties and methods.

```
zedgraph1.PointPairs = new PointPairList();
zedgraph1.Panel = new GraphPane();
```